# Django: cannot import name defaults

Tags: django

It was working well before I started to use `virtualenv`, I made that and suddenly the traceback prompted:

```
File "/home/admort/Projects/django_code/findyourmatch/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 90, in get_response
    response = middleware_method(request)
  File "/home/admort/Projects/django_code/findyourmatch/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 71, in process_request
    if (not urlresolvers.is_valid_path(request.path_info, urlconf) and
  File "/home/admort/Projects/django_code/findyourmatch/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 573, in is_valid_path
    resolve(path, urlconf)
  File "/home/admort/Projects/django_code/findyourmatch/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 453, in resolve
    return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)
  File "/home/admort/Projects/django_code/findyourmatch/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 318, in resolve
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/home/admort/Projects/django_code/findyourmatch/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 346, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/admort/Projects/django_code/findyourmatch/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 341, in urlconf_module
    self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/home/admort/Projects/django_code/findyourmatch/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/admort/Projects/django_code/findyourmatch/findyourmatch/urls.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
ImportError: No module named defaults
```

I have this in `url.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
```

I can not understand the problem, I am here after some tries to solve it.

Comment: Run the python interpreter by hand, and type 'import django'. Most likely django is not installed in your virtualenv and ' pip install django' will take care of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are using Django 1.6

Use:

```
from django.conf.urls import *
```

Also don't import everything. Import only the things you need.

e.g. `from django.conf.urls import patterns`